# Find the probability that among four random digits there occur $3$, $2$, $1$ or $0$ repetitions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Find the probability that among four random digits there occur $3$, $2$, $1$ or $0$ repetitions.

I'm self studying my way through William Feller, an introduction to probability theory and its applications volume 1.

I'm attempted question 7 in chapter 2, and cannot understand the books answer.

With $3$ repetitions, i.e. all digits the same there are 10 possible outcomes therefore $\frac{10}{10^4}$ probability. The book agrees.

With $2$ repetitions, i.e. three digits the same, I thought the answer would be $\binom{4}{3}\times10\times9$. The idea being there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick locations for the three equivalent digits e.g. $aaab$, $aaba$, $abaa$, $baaa$. We have $10$ possible $a$'s and $9$ possible corresponding $b$'s thus $\binom{4}{3}\times10\times9$.

The answer would then be $\frac{360}{10^4} = 0.036$. But the book has it as $0.063$. Where is my mistake?

Incidentally, I wrote a little program to count the digits manually and it reached the same result as my formula.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How is $aabb$ counted?

Comment: @AnotherUser Thanks, I've updated my post.

Comment: If $aaaa$ is $3-$repetitions and $aaab$ is $2$ and presumably $aabc$ is $1$ then I have to assume that $aabb$ is $2$, so your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @lulu, I haven't bothered doing aabb yet. I'm also wondering whether a single instance of aabb counts as 2 instances of 1 repetition or is considered one instance? Considering my answer is incorrect for the easier example of aaab I thought it is pointless to progress untill I understand the simpler of the two.

Comment: As I say, I'd assume that $aabb$ counted as $2$, so your calculation fails to include them.  For $aabb$ there are $\binom {10}2 \times \binom 42=270$ cases, so that means you are off by $.027$ and $.027+.036=.063$

Comment: Well done @lulu, I think you're right. I'm new to this site, how do I select your answer as the best or upvote it?

Comment: No worries. You can't accept a comment, though you are free to post your own solution below.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please include your question in the body of the question, not just the title.